# Raw SQL Query using a list parameter fails

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following code:

```
 products = Product.objects.raw(
            'SELECT DISTINCT ON(I.product_id) P.id, P.name, P.desc, C.name AS ram, I.image '
            'FROM products_product AS P '
            'LEFT JOIN categories AS RPC ON P.id = RPC.product_id '
            'LEFT JOIN company AS CP ON P.company_id = CP.id '
            'LEFT JOIN category AS C ON RPC.category_id = C.id '
            'LEFT JOIN image AS I ON I.product_id = P.id '
            'WHERE P.id IN %s', list
    )
```

I receive the following error:

```
not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Instead of list I tried to use [2,4] or ['2', '4'] , same error.

If I use without a parameter is working.  I use PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [SQL notation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) for `IN()` this could be `IN ('2', '4')`.
So you could try something like:

~'WHERE P.id IN {0}'.format(tuple(your_list))~ << don't.

**EDIT**:

> Warning
>
> Do not use string formatting on raw queries or quote placeholders in
>   your SQL strings!

[Following Django documentation about it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw), you can use:

```
products = Product.objects.raw(
    'SELECT DISTINCT ON(I.product_id) P.id, P.name, P.desc, C.name AS ram, I.image '
    'FROM products_product AS P '
    'LEFT JOIN categories AS RPC ON P.id = RPC.product_id '
    'LEFT JOIN company AS CP ON P.company_id = CP.id '
    'LEFT JOIN category AS C ON RPC.category_id = C.id '
    'LEFT JOIN image AS I ON I.product_id = P.id '
    'WHERE P.id IN %s', params=[your_list])
```

Comment: Don’t use format like this. It doesn’t escape the parameters so it's vulnerable to SQL injection.